# SYSDATE between date in two fields for 6 month period Q

Tags: oracle

I am trying to set between a date range for 6 months in the past for two different fields that will group the data by month.  How do I set such a between clause to achieve this?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(mopend, 'MM-yyyy') AS month, MOPSTATUS, COUNT(*) MTS_COMPLETE_CNT  
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY   
WHERE UPPER(MOPSTATUS) = 'COMPLETE'  
AND TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 06:02:00' AND TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 22:59:59'
OR TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 06:02:00' AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 22:59:59'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(mopend, 'MM-yyyy'), MOPSTATUS  
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(mopend, 'MM-yyyy'), MOPSTATUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer one part of your question first, and then based on your comments, I can give you the full query.

The following query returns the end points between which you want to search. T1 is 06:02 in the morning on the date that is six months back in time. T2 is the last second of today.

```
select sysdate
      ,add_months( trunc(sysdate) + interval '06:02'    hour to minute, -6) as t1
      ,            trunc(sysdate) + interval '23:59:59' hour to second      as t2
  from dual;

The above query returns the following (using yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss):
sydate: 2014-04-11 13:54:28 
t1:     2013-10-11 06:02:00 
t2:     2014-04-11 23:59:59
```

If I interpret you correctly, this is the time period you want to search?
For the second part of the answer, I'd need to know the following:

1. Can any of `MOPSTART` or `MOPEND` be null? If so, how do you want to treat those rows?
2. Do you want to include the end points, i.e. rows where MOPSTART >= t1? Or only where MOTSTART > t1?
3. Same as (2) but for MOPEND
4. What month do you want to group by (see below)?

For example, row (a), do you want count it once for each month, or only in JAN (started) or only in JUN(ended)?

> ```
>       JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN
> a:      |-------------------|
> b:      |---|---|
> c:                      |---|
> d:                      |-----------|
> e:  |--------|
> ```